# How to get User token over skype for business channel in bot framework

Tags: c#, authentication, botframework, skype-for-business

I have created a bot in CSharp and added that bot in Skype for Business Channel.
My use case is so that, this bot can have permission to access the mail and other Graph content of the user. As user is pre-authenticated, it's not a good idea to ask everytime user credentials.

I was searching for an answer for this very long time. can it possible without using a [Signin-Card](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html#signincard). Can someone please help me with some idea that I can refer to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hello there! Please read how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example as to what you have already tried so far. Then tell us what exactly does not work (=explicitly: what is happening and what am I expecting instead). See our guide How to ask for more information

Comment: Have you tried leverage `client-credentials` to access the token for graph without a user, following https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service? And I think as the user are pre-authenticated, so you can get the user id in messages.